# A continuous function with measurable domain.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $D$ and $E$ be measurable sets and $f$ a function with domain $D\cup E$.  We proved that $f$ is measurable on $D \cup E$ if and only if its restrictions to $D$ and $E$ are measurable.  Is the same true if measurable is replaced by continuous.

I wrote the question straight out of the book this time to make sure I did this correctly.  I mechanically replaced measurable with continuous starting with the measurable after $f$.

**Below here is what I wrote before I changed the question**
I've proven the case where continuous is switched for measurable.  I'm just not sure of a meaningful relationship between measurable sets for domains and continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's wrong. Let $f\colon[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be given by 
\[
x\mapsto \begin{cases} 1 & x = 0\\ 0 & x > 0 
\end{cases} \]
Then $f$ is not continuous, but it is, restricted to $D := \{0\}$ and $E := (0,1]$, both of which are measurable.

---

Let me add something concerning your edit: As the example above shows, for just measurable parts $D$ and $E$ continuity of $f|_D$ and $f|_E$ doesn't imply that of $f$ on $D \cup E$. But if both $D$ and $E$ are open in $D \cup E$ or both closed, then your result holds:

For open $D$ and $E$ we argue as follows: Let $U \subseteq \mathbb R$ be open, then we have $f^{-1}[U] = f|_D^{-1}[U] \cup f|_E^{-1}[U]$. Now, $f|_D^{-1}[U]$ is open in $D$ by continuity of $f|_D$, as $D$ is open in $D\cup E$, $f|_D^{-1}[U]$ is also. By the same argument, replacing $D$ by $E$, $f|_E^{-1}[U]$ is open in $D\cup E$, hence $f^{-1}[U]$ is, proving the continuity of $f$.

The case of closed sets can be proved by exactly the same argument, replacing every "open" above by "closed".

Comment: You are... fast! : D

Comment: I changed my question to what it is verbatim from the book.

Comment: I understood from what you wrote after your counter example that it is true if both $D$ and $E$ are open but I do not see this. I do not see why the dependence on the sets upon which $f$ is restricted. As far as I know if $f$ is continuous then the inverse image of every open(U in your case) set is open, Could you please explain to me why the dependence on the openness of the set to which $f$ is being restricted?