# What is the importance of having the set upon which $f$ is restricted open?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to solve this question:

Let $D$ and $E$ be measurable sets and $f$ a function with domain $D \cup E.$ We proved that $f$ is measurable on $D \cup E$ if and only if its restrictions to $D$ and $E$ are measurable. Is the same true if "measurable" is replaced by "continuous"?

I know that the question is asking me is the following statement true or not:

$f$ is continuous on $D \cup E$ if and only if its restrictions to $D$ and $E$ are continuous.

I also know that the forward direction is true just by the definition of continuity, and I also know that the backward direction is not true in general but in the following link [A continuous function with measurable domain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216771/a-continuous-function-with-measurable-domain/216772#216772) it said that it is true if both $D$ and $E$ are open but I do not see this. I do not see why the dependence on the sets upon which $f$ is restricted. As far as I know if $f$ is continuous then the inverse image of every open(U in the link) set is open, Could anyone explain to me why the dependence on the openness of the set to which $f$ is being restricted?

**EDIT:**

Here is the solution given in the link above:

That's wrong. Let $f\colon[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be given by
\[
x\mapsto \begin{cases} 1 & x = 0\\ 0 & x > 0 
\end{cases} \]
Then $f$ is not continuous, but it is, restricted to $D := \{0\}$ and $E := (0,1]$, both of which are measurable.

---

Let me add something concerning your edit: As the example above shows, for just measurable parts $D$ and $E$ continuity of $f|_D$ and $f|_E$ doesn't imply that of $f$ on $D \cup E$. But if both $D$ and $E$ are open in $D \cup E$ or both closed, then your result holds:

For open $D$ and $E$ we argue as follows: Let $U \subseteq \mathbb R$ be open, then we have $f^{-1}[U] = f|_D^{-1}[U] \cup f|_E^{-1}[U]$. Now, $f|_D^{-1}[U]$ is open in $D$ by continuity of $f|_D$, as $D$ is open in $D\cup E$, $f|_D^{-1}[U]$ is also. By the same argument, replacing $D$ by $E$, $f|_E^{-1}[U]$ is open in $D\cup E$, hence $f^{-1}[U]$ is, proving the continuity of $f$.

The case of closed sets can be proved by exactly the same argument, replacing every "open" above by "closed".

Comment: I am voting to close, because this question should be a comment asking for further clarification or explanation to the answer to the linked question. Effectively this is a duplicate.

Comment: Are you sure that the author will reply quickly?@RobArthan the question is from 2019. I usually check the last time the authors enter and if I found them active I leave a comment and if not I just post a question ..... the thing is that in this new format of your site I am unable to check when were the member on the site last time.

Comment: The other question is quite old, but the answerer is very active (you should be able to see this by clicking on the name and then clicking on activity). Why not try a comment on the other question and see what happens. If you don't get a response, then ask a question that is much more focussed on what you do and don't understand in the proof.

Comment: @Brain StackExchange will, by default, send you emails notifying you of messages directed at you if you are offline for more than a few days. It's probably worth a shot. That said, I don't think this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @RobArthan I clicked on the activity (certainly I have did this before) and I could not see the last time he was on site, could you please tell me exactly at which part of the page of activity I could find this information(I used to find it before you updated your site)?

Comment: I am not involved in the maintenance of the site: if you have issues with changes then I suggest you raise them on Help or Meta. It isn't too hard to navigate to a user's recent activity/reputation changes.

Comment: @RobArthan just to let you know, I posted a comment under the answer in the other question and I did not receive any response yet. Once I receive a response, I will delete my question here, otherwise, I will not be able to have an answer to my question at all, as you closed this question.

Comment: @RobArthan are you a moderator?